# How to find an efficient algorithm to identify for each x the smallest n and k such that f^(n)(x) = f^(n+k)(x)

Tags: algorithm, loops, linked-list

The titular question is associated to the following problem: https://i.gyazo.com/07b7dde7efe1df0b7ae9550317851fda.png

And a more detailed explanation of the titular problem can be provided but I can't post more than two links so if someone replies and asks for it I can provide it to you!

To start, I understand that the whole question is based upon the idea of the tortoise and hare algorithm for cycle detection (I would link the Wikipedia page, but I don't have enough reputation). I also understand that the existence of a loop is proven by the tortoise and hare 'meeting up' with each other after leaving the first node. I also know that where they meet up for the second time in the second phase of the algorithm is indicative of exactly where the loop begins.

Unfortunately, I simply can't wrap my head around relating this/these facts to the question given and how to create an algorithm for it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "Almost" featured on [CS](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/53302/19966)

Comment: You mean you don't understand how this problem relates to the link?  Easy: f(x) = x.next.   f^2(x) = (x.next).next, etc.

Comment: How does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection not answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

No idea how you're supposed to make an algorithm for it, but it seems like simple modulo math. `T(x) = x mod 5` and `H(x) = 2x mod 5`. You're asked to solve for when `T(x) = H(x)`. Since both expression are modulo 5, you know they're equal when `2x - x = 5k` where `k` is some integer.